Spring boot WebClient connection freezes due to TooLongFrameException: HTTP header is larger than 8192 bytes
I am using a webclient to connect to a downstream API, after getting the response from downstream, my service throws a warning message as given below:
2024-05-01 20:04:08,240 [reactor-http-nio-1] traceId:[] **WARN**  r.n.http.client.HttpClientConnect#299 -> [id: 0x7fa2c1c0, L:/127.0.0.1:55568 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:3000] The connection observed an error
io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: HTTP header is larger than 8192 bytes.
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder$HeaderParser.newException(HttpObjectDecoder.java:951)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder$HeaderParser.increaseCount(HttpObjectDecoder.java:946)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder$HeaderParser.process(HttpObjectDecoder.java:934)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.forEachByteAsc0(AbstractByteBuf.java:1301)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.forEachByte(AbstractByteBuf.java:1281)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder$HeaderParser.parse(HttpObjectDecoder.java:908)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder.readHeaders(HttpObjectDecoder.java:593)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder.decode(HttpObjectDecoder.java:255)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.decode(HttpClientCodec.java:225)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)

This error is coming as a Warning, but in the subsequent call to the same url endpoint, the webclient connection pool gets exhausted, and I get:
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Pool#acquire(Duration) has been pending for more than t
he configured timeout of 45000ms;

Note: the above header exception is caught and handled accordingly.
All the subsequent calls to the downstream are not able to connect, and get the above timeout exception.
**I think this connection pool exhaustion is due to that the connection is still not released after the above large header warning. **
I have increased the size of the header size of the response headers to 100kb using the given method while creating a bean for the webClient in my configuration file.
httpResponseDecoder(res -> res.maxHeaderSize(maxHeaderSize));

This is resolving my issue for now.
But I am still not sure why a large header warning is exhausting the connections in webClient connection pool.
I am assuming this above mentioned theory: **this connection pool exhaustion is due to the fact that the connection is not released after the above large header warning. **
Is there any way to close or release the aquired connection in the Webclient after some time? Or can we configure any timeout?
We can reproduce this issue by sending a large response header(size larger than 8192 char) from mockoon, or by reducing the macHeaderSize using the aforementioned solution.

I need more clarification on why connections are not released after this WARN  r.n.http.client.HttpClientConnect#299 -> [id: 0x7fa2c1c0, L:/127.0.0.1:55568 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:3000] The connection observed an error
io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: HTTP header is larger than 8192 bytes.

There is a way to set timeout for a webclient connection. Give this a shot.
 WebClient client = WebClient.create();
    client.get()
            .uri("/someURL")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(Object.class)
            .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(10_000));


Is there any way to configure the same while creating bean of webclient.

can you try this, i dont have access to pc atm, so I cant confirm if it'll work
 @Bean   public WebClient webClient() {     WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()       .baseUrl("someURL")       .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(10_000)       .build();   }
